# How to display a custom list in ASP.NET webform

Tags: asp.net, label, blogs, dynamic-data

I am working on an ASP.NET webform that functions similar to a blog. On the main form I want to display a list of the recent post titles and under each the first 75 characters of the post text. What would be a good control to use to display these titles/descriptions? Should I just dynamically add Labels into an  on the page or is there a better way?

Comment: use html unordered list instead...generate it dynamically and you can use alternating colors for the entires by using jquery/css...

Comment: @user648372 the main point of the question exactly about how to generate `ul` element

Answer (score 0):

In WebForms use the [`<asp:ListView>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx) control. It allows full flexibility for the markup while binding to a data source that provides the model of your blog entries.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use the `<asp:Repeater>` control, and use `<li>` html elements in it's `<ItemTemplate>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to displaay some data, without any edit or sorting, use one of the 2 light data bound controls: [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx):

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server">
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
        <%-- Add 75 chars of text here. --%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

or [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Name</th>
        <th>
          Description</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
        <%-- Add 75 chars of text here. --%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

use html unordered list instead...generate it dynamically and you can use alternating colors for the entires by using jquery/css

In Csharp define a string this way, which would be static

```
string mainDiv = "<div class=\"Container\"><ul id=\"BlogPost\">";
```

the dynamic li for every post.

```
string dynamic= string.empty;

dynamic += "<li>" + ContentYouExtractFromdatabase + "<hr></li>";

newDynamicLink = mainDiv + dynamic + "</ul></div>";
```

now keep appending your li's depending upon the post you receive.